# Trigger CoreLocation Alert

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location, alasset, alassetslibrary

I am using the AssetsLibrary to access the images in the photo roll on IOS.
Whenever an app tries to use the AssetsLibrary an CoreLocation alert pops up, asking the user to authorize the app to use location services.
I understand that this is mandatory because the ALAssets contain location information.
My problem is that I am not able to figure out how to proceed when the user clicks "No".
How to find out if the authorization was granted and is there a way to trigger the authorization request again if the user didn't granted the access to location services.

Please help,

Arno

Answer (score 1):

CoreLocation has that built in. locationServicesEnabled. If it isn't enabled, you could prompt the user to enable them in settings.